# How to use shortcuts of integrated terminal in Visual Studio(2022)?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2022, conflict, cmder

I use Cmder as a terminal when using Windows. I also use this terminal on any IDE (Vscode/IntellijIDEA). My reason for using it is that it makes it possible to use the features of the Linux terminal on windows.
For example CTRL+R (Recall the last command matching the characters you provide).
When I want to use this shortcut on VisualStudio(2022), it conflicts with the Globally assigned shortcuts. I wonder if I can disable the globally assigned shortcuts in VisualStudio specifically for the terminal? Or if there is a matching shortcut in the terminal, can I make it work primarily?

I tried disabling the conflicting shortcuts on Visual Studio(2022), but I couldn't get the result I wanted because there were too many shortcuts for the terminal.I also changed the default keyboard mapping scheme, still didn't work.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem when using the integrated Terminal in Visual Studio to run the `dotnet watch` command.

It instructs you to `Press "Ctrl + R" to restart`, but that doesn't have any effect, other than a message in the Visual Studio status bar saying `(Ctrl+R) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord...`, because `Ctrl-R` is bound to dozens of commands in the VS keyboard binding.

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to resolve the conflict between Terminal keyboard commands and VS Global commands.

Answer (score 3):

After some experimenting/guessing, I found that `Ctrl+Shift+R` in the Visual Studio 2022 integrated Terminal seems to have the same effect in `dotnet watch` as `Ctrl+R` when running in a standalone PowerShell terminal.

I'm not sure if this solution is specific to `dotnet watch` or not, but maybe `Ctrl+Shift+R` will work for you in the context of `Cmder`.

Comment: OMFG I could kiss you!! I've spent the past hour searching for a solution to this extremely annoying problem, and even went through **every single Ctrl+R related shortcut** in `Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard` and unassigned them all, to no avail. But this works!! Halle-freaking-lujah!!

Comment: My years of struggle finally get rested here. Thank you lord Brett